# Cant understand or fix com.android.tools.build:gradle is no set in the build.gradle file Android studio

Tags: android, gradle

Trying to create an app using Huawei appGallery, but whenever I add the SDK and try to sync I get this error. Tried re-installing everthing but the same error keeps coming up and I dont understand it.
Error: com.android.tools.build:gradle is no set in the build.gradle
build.gradle (project)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        //Add the Maven address.
            maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.5.2.300'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

build.gradle (app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.first.a1806957'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.first.a1806957"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.5.2.300'
}

apply plugin: 'com.huawei.agconnect'
```

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4' 

add this in line in buildScript -> dependencies. Project Level Gradle

Comment: Thanks it worked but now I am encountering a new error, cant use/import com.huawei.agconnect.auth says cannot be imported but doesnt read it when I add as as package even though the dependency is read and working fine